# armv61 support for GNSDK

Tags: gracenote

I am trying to compile the samples from gnsdk on a Raspberry Pi (model B, I guess). But I get an "illegal instruction" when I run the sample.

Can I do something clever?

Thanks in advance.

/Simon C

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile that sample source code by using cross compile?

Comment: No. I compiled on the raspberry pi. I have been told that the gnsdk binaries are for armv7, which is the processor on raspberry pi 2. Moreover I've heard of a successful run on raspberry pi 3. Apparently I have a raspberry pi 1, and should start saving money for a newer model as Gracenote doesn't want to support the armv6.

Comment: sorry for get back too late. Last year I applied gnsdk to develop an application to search music by using melody. The platform is Embedded Linux, hardware is armv7 Freescale.

Comment: I have succeded on a arm7 processor.